# Can I use Grails Plugin classes outside a Grails project as a Jar dependency?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I have found some code in grails plugins  that can be use outside grails. Is there a way to use the code from the plugin as a dependency in a groovy project other than creating two projects?

For example I found the following project:

https://github.com/jeffellis/grails-yammer-metrics

Where they created some annotations for Groovy code that I would like to use outside a grails project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of grails 2.1, you can export a plugin as a binary plugin and then declare as a regular jar dependency (via grape in groovy). http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#binaryPlugins

How reusable the code is would depend on how closely coupled the plugin is to the code, I guess.